# Can't add option object to the SHA3 function with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, cryptojs

the `SHA3` function provides an option to control the output length as shown in this example:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", { outputLength: 512 });
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", { outputLength: 384 });
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", { outputLength: 256 });
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", { outputLength: 224 });
```

however when used in typescript with [@types/crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/crypto-js) i am getting the following type error when trying to specify the the `outputLength`:

> Argument of type '{ outputLength: number; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'string | WordArray | undefined'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'outputLength' does not exist in type 'string | WordArray |
>   undefined'.

Comment: Your code looks correct so far, can you please add your `import` statement to the original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that function is defined, in `@types/crypto-js`, as:

```
(message: string | LibWordArray, key?: string | WordArray, ...options: any[]) => WordArray;
```

As you see, it expects three parameters, the second being the key (which is nullable). Just do this:

```
CryptoJS.SHA3("Message", undefined, { outputLength: 512});
```

An it should work.

By the way, there's another @types for this library, `@types\cryptojs`, it might suit you better.

Comment: ummm thank it works! but wired the key parameter is optional with the `?` maybe we should add a default value to it as undefined would that solve the issue?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. A default value? For key?

Comment: Yes in the @types/crypto-js file. Is it possible?